# Reflected light and color fade

Tags: visible-light

The color of many objects fade with constant sunlight. Is the reflected light "leaching" the color, is it carrying something substantial away? What is expending the color? This is not about jangling electrons, it's about what gets carried off from the surface with the reflected light. Obviously, the color itself. How can it give so generously? Maybe the UV de-stabilization frees up it's release. The light does a bounce, but only one color emerges as scattered light. Is that light free of content from the surface? Does it leave the surface unharmed?

Answer (score 2):

If you shine white light on a colored object, chemicals (or dyes) in the object determine which colors are absorbed and which reflected. Over time, light damages the dyes, and they lose their ability to absorb.

This typically happens to red dyes first. When red is reflected, it is because other colors such as blue, are absorbed. Blue light is more energetic than other colors, and more able to do damage.

Answer (score 0):

> The color of many objects fade with constant sunlight

It's not just constant sunlight that causes coloured objects to fade over time, intermittent sunlight does it too.

Manufactured coloured objects can broadly speaking be divided into:

1. Their material, often a plastic or elastomer, is coloured because it contains a colouring dye,
2. Their material is coloured because it contains (or is made up of) a colouring pigment.

Pigments are usually inorganic substances like titanium dioxide, zinc oxide or graphite (and many, many others). These tend to be chemically very resistant to UV/VIS and tend to maintain their colour for prolonged periods of time.

But colouring dyes are organic compounds that owe their colour mainly to so-called chemical double bonds (a.k.a. $\pi$-bonds) These dyes tend to degrade (be destroyed) by UV/VIS fairly fast, so that the objects that contain them fade in colour relatively quickly.